# Detecting visible sheets in Excel tabs list displayed at bottom of Excel application

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

Is it possible using VBA to determine whether or not a given sheet is currently visible in the list displayed at the bottom left corner of the window?

The Excel Window object has a ScrollWorkbookTabs method, but doesn't appear to expose any events. I'd like to be able to detect when the navigation buttons on the left side of the tabs list have been clicked so I can determine if a certain spreadsheet is visible in the tabs list.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  The visible tab list will change based on both the screen resolution and the length of name of each sheet, and there are no native API calls that can tell you what's currently there.

The best workaround I've used to this problem (several sheets which are difficult to navigate) is to create a navigation header that gets inserted into each worksheet which enables the user to quickly move around the workbook.